# Only browser works fine plus some apps Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

CMD shell has no text

Windows menu are squished and even taking a screenshot is impossible because explorer shows zero names for folders and files.

Steam menu has the login box but no text on the menu

Comment: Do you have a question? [How to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is either very corrupted or badly infected.

Since you cannot use CMD, you cannot do the most useful troubleshooting operations
such as `chkdsk` and
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

I suggest to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
If this helps, run `chkdsk` and `sfc /scannow`, followed by deep antivirus scans
by several well-known products.

If this doesn't help, then Windows needs to be reinstalled from scratch.

Comment: That happened with me when I purposely deleted the ctfmon.exe. most of the font/text became invisible, then I copied it from my another pc, it somewhat worked but I still refreshed the windows.